# Bash How to move folders based on size

Tags: linux, bash

Currently I have a script that saves my streams to a folder called 'archive', I would like for the folder to be moved onto my desktop once the folder size reaches either 4Mb or higher, Is there a command I can use to help me with this?

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. You could start by reading the `du` manual (`man du`). As soon as you will have a first draft of your bash script, if it does not work as you expect, please show it and we'll try to help.

Comment: What do you mean by "once"?  Do you want the directory to be moved into your desktop within a few milliseconds of an entry being added to it that increases the sum of the sizes of the entries, or within 24 hours?  Is the directory of interest mounted on the same file system as your desktop?  Do you only care about new entries to the directory, or are you interested in existing files which are growing?  Are the files listed in the directory decreasing in size? By "folder size", do you even mean the sum of the sizes of the entries, or do you mean the actual size of the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have read at least the manual of `du` (as Renaud Pascalet told you), you will like to try next command:

```sh
if [ $(du -m -s archive/ | cut -f1) -gt 4 ] ; then 
  mv archive/ $HOME/Desktop/
fi
```

Comment: ... and this you put in the crontab :-)

Comment: @Dominique: indeed, but in that case, it is wise to change `$HOME` by the full path of the user.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted, I was able to add this to my script and it works like a charm.